# load script with async ajax request vs embedding it with script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

what is the difference between loading and executing script with async ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax('/script.js', {
        datatype: "script",
        async: false
    })
</script>
```

vs embedding it with script tag

```
<script src="/script.js" />
```

?

ps script.js is dynamically generated on server and when user uses back button he gets stale version of that script from cache, if embedding it with script tag, so I want to load it with ajax (I need it to be ready before page load event occurs)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `$.getScript()` instead of `$.ajax()`? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: @TaoP.R. it 's the same

Comment: Of course, just a syntactic sugar to make it semantically implies script loading, less ambiguous with ajax call for something (personal opinion).